# Why does the context hang around after a with statement?

Tags: python, file-io

I would like to know why a file object opened using `with` statement or in a block, remains in scope after exit.  Are `<closed file>` objects ever cleaned up?

```
>>> with open('test.txt','w') as f:
...     f.write('test')
...
>>> f
<closed file 'test.txt', mode 'w' at 0x00E014F0>
>>> f.close()


>>> if True:
...     fal = open('demo.txt','w')
...     fal.write('stuff')
...     fal.close()
...
>>> fal
<closed file 'demo.txt', mode 'w' at 0x00E015A0>
```

Comment: Here’s [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for some light reading.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Python new scopes (aka namespaces) are *only* created for modules, classes and functions, but not for any other statement, especially not for `with` and `if` blocks.  Identifiers bound within the body of `with` or `for` statements are consequently bound in the inner-most surrounding scope, which is the top-level scope of the interactive interpreter in your case.   Identifiers are bound in a scope as long as this scope is valid, or until they are explicitly removed from the scope (by using `del` as in `del fal`).

Objects can only be cleaned up when they are not longer referenced.  The actual moment, in which this object is really cleaned up, is however undefined.  Python uses garbage collection for memory management, and doesn't enforce a specific strategy.  In CPython, which uses reference counting, objects are immediately cleaned up, once the last reference goes out of scope.  Alternative implementations like PyPy or Jython use more advanced garbage collectors, which clean up unreferenced objects at arbitrary points of time.

This means, that in your example the objects bound to `f` and `fal` are bascially never cleaned up, because the top-level scope of the interactive interpreter does naturally exist as long as the interpeter is running.  Beware however, that this is not actually a problem, because they are nevertheless correctly closed and do not claim any file resource anymore, but only some memory.

Comment: Thank you for the well put response.

Comment: To be clear, they are still consuming resources, just not the file resource.

Answer (score 4):

The name will remain in scope untill you leave the scope.

If you want the object cleaned up, assign a different value to the name, like

```
f = None
```

This does not close the file!

It is a good habit to make the scopes limited by structuring the program in to functions ( and possibly classes ). That makes it more readable and makes unbound objects (no names in scope which refer to the object ) elegible for garbage collection.

This is usually not an issue when you're using the prompt though :)

Comment: The file *is* closed. Even `repr` tells you that. But a closed file doesn't delete the handle and magically makes all references disappear. Otherwise good answer and actually touching the scope issue, so +1.

Comment: @delnan in this case it is. I just wanted to make explicit that a file disappearing from the context does not necessarilly close it.

Comment: When used in a `with` block, is *will* be closed unless the interpreter crashes. But yes, just removing one reference to it generally won't cause it to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

`with` and `if` don't create a new scope, local variables are only created within functions, classes, and modules.  See [What's the scope of a Python variable declared in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-python-variable-declared-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

The file object, like any other object, 'hangs around' for the duration of your program, until it's deleted (its `__del__` method is called).

`del f` will cause `f` to be garbage collected by Python's garbage collector. This happens automatically when you exit a scope, your script terminates, or in your example, the interpreter session ends.

Comment: This is misleading. Python will delete the object when there are no more references, and `del f` will only remove one reference to the object referenced by `f`.

Comment: Right, but I was referring to `del f` as part of his example, where it only has one reference (he COULD read into the intricacies of the python GC's reference-counting mechanism for a deeper explanation).

Comment: If that's the case, then should the '__exit__ wrapper that's part of the with() statment, call __del__, I don't understand how scoping the variable inside the with statement, doesn't cause it to be fully cleaned up. In my example, there were no more references to 'f'. It was declared right within the 'with()' statement

Comment: `__del__()` is not necessarily invoked, when objects are deleted.  The mere existence of this methods in the class namespace may actually prevent the object from being garbage-collected.

Comment: @pyInTheSky: It can't (you can't modify the caller's scope, which is a very good thing btw!) and there are times where you don't want it. And even if you don't need it around, it doesn't matter. You make two wrong assumptions: (1) That GC of the object is required for cleanup (all cleanup is in `__exit__`, only memory for the actual context manager isn't reclaimed) and (2) that `with` has it's own scope (it doesn't - in your example `f` is still around because of this).

Comment: @delnan: only 2 :p, thanks for the clarifications.  At the end of the day, I wish i could do f.open() if it's going to stick around.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `with` statement calls the file class's `__exit__` method [which ,in the case of files, closes them].  It does not delete the object; it is cleaned up only when you explicitly clean it up or close the program/interpreter.

Comment: ... which would be asynch with GC anyway. To expand, the variable is still around because `with` doesn't introduce it's own scope.