# Why can a python function use a variable in the global scope before it's defined?

Tags: python

```
def foo(i):
  print len(A)
  return i < len(A)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  A = [12]
  print A 
  foo(10)
```

How can `foo` know about `A`?

I am writing this because stackoverflow insists that I write some more words.

Comment: A is a global name. It is visible to the functions in the same namespace, aka the current module.

Comment: since you do it in `if __name__ == "__main__":` any variables are part of the global namespace ... which is searched if a variable cant be found in the local namespace ... if you created it in a function named main it would not be visible outside of that function unless it was explicitly declared as global

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) has more information about how scope works in python. Basically `if` statements don't create a new scope so `A` is in the global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is a global variable.  You may be thinking that it is local to the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, but [if statements do not create a separate namespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-python-variable-declared-in-an-if-statement).  When `foo` is executed (not defined) the variable `A` exists in the global namespace so your current code runs without any issues.

If you want to see your expected behavior move everything from that block into a function and then call that from within the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block:

```
def foo(i):
  print len(A)      # A is local to main(), so this will raise an exception
  return i < len(A)

def main():
  A = [12]
  print A 
  foo(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the generated bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print) 
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len) 
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (A) 
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             15 POP_TOP              

  3          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (i) 
             19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len) 
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (A) 
             25 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             28 COMPARE_OP               0 (<) 
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

To load the `A` variable it uses the `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode. So, when the function runs (**and not at definition**) it will search for this variable in the global namespace

Comment: +1 because you were the first to answer and you went through the trouble to pull up the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Because A is defined in the global scope, and isn't looked up in the function until it's called.

It's the same reason

```
def should_fail():
   print undefined_variable

print "runs OK!"
```

runs OK.