# Python, pausing a subprocess based on the received messages

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new here and new to the whole Python coding and my programming knowledge is low.
I am designing a code that receives an IM on GTalk and based on the received messages a subprocess (mp4 or mp3 file on OMXPlayer) will run. at the moment i can run the subprocess but I can't pause/stop the mp3/mp4 files (subprocess). Any suggestion?

```
def message_handler(connect_object, message_node):

    R = (message_node.getBody())

    if R == "video" :

        movie_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/media/video.mp4'
        p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer',movie_path])

    elif R == "music" :

        movie_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/media/music.mp3'
        p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer',movie_path])

    elif R == "pause":

        p.kill() # it gives me erroe "p is not defined"
        os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGSTOP) # doesn't do nothing

   else:

       pass
```

Comment: Have you defined p elsewhere, outside `message_handlers` scope?

Comment: A little more detai on what Skurmedel is getting at. "p" will be newly defined  for each invocation of `message_handler`. You want to save the `subprocess.Popen` somewhere with more permanent scope, so that the pause message can find the proper subprocess. Note the possibility of there being multiple subprocesses (playing more than one video at a time), so you need some way to track that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with regards to this. Firstly, your variable "p" is defined inside the if blocks, and are thus not available outside that particular block.
Second, you are not actually pausing the process, you are telling it to terminate. What you probably want to do is create a named pipe to your omxplayer process and feed instructions through that to omxplayer. This is, however, quite a bit more advanced. (Or not, as research progressed)

```
p = None #This initializes the variables globally.

def message_handler(connect_object, message_node):
    R = (message_node.getBody())
    if R== "video" :
        movie_path= '/home/pi/Desktop/media/video.mp4'
        p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', movie_path],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    elif R== "pause":
        p.stdin.write('\x20') #Much cleaner alternative to named pipes...
    else:
        pass
```

Note that this is not complete code, it is merely a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: *"Firstly, your variable "p" is defined inside the if blocks, and are thus not available outside that particular block"* This isn't actually the case in Python. In Python, variables are always bound to the innermost function or module. So variables defined in an `if` block are in scope anywhere inside the function the `if` block occurs in. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2829528/2073595)

Comment: `//` is not how to add comments to python code, probably worth pointing out before the OP ends up more confused.

Comment: Also, the `Popen` command as written will not work, because it's using shell redirection (`<`), and passes the entire command as a string, but isn't using `shell=True`. You should also use the `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` keyword argument to feed data to a process' stdin via `Popen`, not a named pipe.

Comment: @KennethAalberg I'll be happy to reverse mine once those issues are fixed.

Comment: @KennethAalberg You wouldn't want to use `communicate` to pause, because it will block until the program exits (I'm assuming omxplayer won't exit when it gets the pause command). You should just use `p.stdin.write('\x20')`.

Comment: @dano I referred to this re. choosing communicate over stdin.write: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Comment: @KennethAalberg It's definitely safer to use `communicate` in general, because you don't run the risk of a pipe filling up and causing a deadlock. But we can't use it here because we don't want to wait for the process to exit. It should also be safe to write directly to stdin in this case; we're just sending a small amount of data, so we shouldn't fill the pipe.

Comment: I tried your code it gives me "UnboundedLocalError: local variable 'p' referenced before assignment". I don't know much, i just copied what you've written and pasted it there. and that was the result. i would like more explanation, like what is the '\x20' ? and what topic should i read about? piping ? popen and subprocess? i am sorry for all this questions, it is just my knowledge are at minimum, i am willing to put some work, if i am pointed in the right direction.

Comment: The code is not fit to be pasted and used directly, it is provided as a pointer in the general direction. The '\x20' is a keycode, namely the keycode for the spacebar, which is the default key for pausing and restarting playback. Piping is basically providing a way for you to communicate with the process programmatically. Read up about popen.subprocess and using pipes in the Python online manual. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html for instance.

Comment: Listen, I have added "global p" under "def" and it works.. it pauses the video.. thank you so much :)

Comment: @KennethAalberg: one more question, now if i send "video" the video plays, and if i followed that with "music" the music file plays, so the video and the music are playing at the same time. is there away? like if the video was playing when receving "music"  the video will close and the music will play. i tried adding "p.stdin.write" just before the "movie_path" but that didn't work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable like `p` within a function, it only exists within that function's *namespace* - the list of defined variables and functions accessible at that point in time. You're creating the subprocess object with `popen` and binding it to `p` within the function `message_handler`, and it's in that namespace that `p` exists. Once `message_handler` exits, its namespace disappears with it - and so does the binding to `p`. Then the next time you access `message_handler`, you have no hope of accessing the same object.

A better option is to have your function accept and return the object:

```
def message_handler(connect_object, message_node, p):

    R = (message_node.getBody())

    if R  == "video" :

        movie_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/media/video.mp4'
        p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer',movie_path])

    elif R == "music" :

        movie_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/media/music.mp3'
        p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer',movie_path])

    elif R == "pause":

        p.kill() # it gives me erroe "p is not defined"
        os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGSTOP) # doesn't do nothing

   else:

       pass

   return p
```

If you do it this way, `p` has been defined outside of the function, and now exists in whatever namespace you call the function from.

Now, as Kenneth Aalberg noted, your code probably isn't going to pause correctly, and you'll need to find another method. But this should answer one of your questions, at least.

Comment: using `global` is very rarely the way to go

Comment: it says "TypeError: message_handler() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)"

Comment: @user3828628 yes, I added another argument at the end, for you to pass in the subprocess object `p`.

Comment: I wrote the exact code and that error was the result

Comment: @user3828628 are you calling the function the exact same way you did before? You should be passing in either a blank variable or the `Popen` object you got when you first called the function. That's your third argument.