# Variables defined inside if or for statements

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, for-loop, garbage-collection

What happens to variables assigned for the first time (defined) inside `if` statement or `for` loop if long time passed from when their code run. Is there some sort of garbage collection that may result in a not defined variable exception. For example:

```
if True:
   a=1
else:
   a=3
# long time passed and other codes run
# .
# .
# .
print (a)
```

I encountered an error in my code that I suspect this to be the reason. Is it documented somewhere in official Python documentation ?

Comment: Unless your variables moves out of scope it should not be garbage collected. Thats how ref counting works (the way Python garbage collects).

Comment: variables stay, as long as the scope exists, unless they are removed by `del a`.

Comment: Why do you suspect that is the reason? The code you post doesn't come close to reproducing your suspected error.

Comment: could u try print(a) right after the if else statement as a way of debugging?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the scope of a Python variable declared in an if statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-python-variable-declared-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: @ScottLawson yes it's a duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, if you define a variable within an `if` statement, it will continue to exist after the `if` statement concludes. Scopes are defined for a `class`, a `def`, or the global scope; if you're in a function and you define a variable inside `if`, for example, that variable will exist until the function is done executing.

**Be careful**, however, of defining variables in code like this:

```
if x == True:
  a = 1
else:
  print "Not true"
```

If you have code like this, and `x` ends up being `False`, then **`a` will not be defined.** Later calls to `a` will throw an exception as a result. So make sure that you get rid of any potential problems of that sort.