# Local variable scope in Java vs Python

Tags: java, python, scope

When I try to access the local variable jimFound outside of the block it was declared in the first Java code piece I get a compilation error

Error:(10, 13) java: cannot find symbol,
 symbol:   variable jimFound,
 location: class Scope

Which is what I expected.

```
public class Scope { 
    public void main(String args[]){
        String name = "Jim";
        if (name.equals("Jim")) {
            boolean jimFound = true;
        }
        if(jimFound) {
            System.out.println("I found Jim!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I try the same with Python my program manages to find Jim.

```
name = "Jim"
if name == "Jim":
    jim_found = True
if jim_found:
    print "I found Jim!"
```

The console result is "I found Jim!"

Why is this happening?

Comment: In Java a variable is scoped inside its _block_ - simply said the closest pair of curly brackets (with some exceptions). So `jimFound` only exists _inside_ the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python variables are scoped to the innermost function or module; control blocks like `if` and `while` blocks don't count.

[What's the scope of a Python variable declared in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-python-variable-declared-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: So it's just a very different approach of scoping, but I find it very confusing. This way in Python it happens a lot to get a "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'some_variable' referenced before assignment"