# How does Python print a variable that is out of scope

Tags: python, block

I have the following function in Python that seems to be working:

```
def test(self):
    x = -1
    # why don't I need to initialize y = 0 here?
    if (x < 0):
        y = 23

    return y
```

But for this to work why don't I need to initialize variable y? I thought Python had block scope so how is this possible?

Comment: It works because you assign `y`. If you didn't, it wouldn't.

Comment: Python has function scope - the variable is attached to the function it lives in... if it is declared outside of a function then to the module.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a simple misunderstanding about [scope in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/674039).  Conditional statements don't create a scope.  The name `y` is in the local scope inside the function, because of this statement which is present in the syntax tree:

```
y = 23
```

This is determined at function definition time, when the function is parsed.  The fact that the name `y` might be used whilst unbound at runtime is irrelevant.

Here's a simpler example highlighting the same issue:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return y
...     y = 23
... 
>>> def bar():
...     return y
... 
>>> foo.func_code.co_varnames
('y',)
>>> bar.func_code.co_varnames
()
>>> foo()
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
>>> bar()
# NameError: global name 'y' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you misunderstood this part of [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html):

> A Python program is constructed from code blocks. A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition.
>   ...
>   A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block.

So in this case block is *something completely different* from visual blocks of your code. Thereby `if`, `for`, `while` statements doesn't have their own scopes. But it is worth noting that **comprehensions and generator expressions are implemented using a function scope**, so they have their own scopes.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no block scope in python.
Variables may be local (inside of a function) or global (same for the whole scope of the program).

Once you've defined the variable y inside the 'if' block its value is kept for this specific function until you specifically delete it using the 'del' command, or the function exits.
From the moment y is defined in the function, it is a local variable of this function.

Answer (score 0):

As in [What's the scope of a Python variable declared in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-python-variable-declared-in-an-if-statement): "Python variables are scoped to the innermost function or module; control blocks like if and while blocks don't count."

Also useful: [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)