# Recommended way for variable scoping in python

Tags: python, scope

In C and variants, when you have something like this:

```
{
  tmp1 <- 5
  tmp2 <- 2
  print(tmp1 + tmp2)
}
```

a 7 will be printed, but the `tmp1` and `tmp2` variables will be removed from stack once the scope `}` ends. I sometimes want similar functionality in python so that I do not have to clean up (many) temporary variables after some point in time.

In R one can use `local({insert piece of code})` for exactly this purpose.

How do we get similar but readable behavior in python?

Comment: Don't try to program C in Python. Python does not have block scope, don't try to simulate it. You don't need to clean up variables.

Answer (score 2):

There is not any special syntax for that, but you can achieve something like that, by deleting the variables manually:

```
tmp1 = 5
tmp2 = 2

print(tmp1 + tmp2)

del tmp1
del tmp2
```

If you don't like this syntax you can use:

```
def local(f): 
  f()

@local
def block(): 
  tmp1 = 5
  tmp2 = 2
  print(tmp1 + tmp2)
```

That is basically same as:

```
def block(): 
   ...
local(block)
```

(https://hackernoon.com/decorators-in-python-8fd0dce93c08)

But the point is really unidiomatic.

Comment: Interesting answer. Since I was hoping for something readable/comprehensible, I can not accept it. But you could further improve your answer by explaining why the definition evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can implement something tricky to simulate.

```
import inspect
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def Local():
    enter_locals = set(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals.keys())
    yield
    exit_locals = set(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals.keys())
    substract = exit_locals - enter_locals
    for variable in substract:
        del inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals[variable]

with Local():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    print(a + b)

print(a + b)

# 3
# ...
# ----> 6 print(a + b)
#
# NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

But it is really not recommended. Why you want to simulate other languages in Python? Python is Python, no block scope, is no block scope.

Comment: Python is (mis)used in many different contexts. I am aware that there is no block scope (neither there is in R), but it doesn't mean that there are no ways to get similar behavior. Hence the question.

Comment: The code snippet given in answer shows a simple simulation.

Answer (score 1):

OK an engineered solution finally, with which you can still intentionally leak selected variables.

```
from scoping import scoping
a = 2
with scoping():
    assert(2 == a)
    a = 3
    b = 4
    scoping.keep('b')
    assert(3 == a)
assert(2 == a)
assert(4 == b)
```

https://github.com/l74d/scoping

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/51685 for the skinny on Python's variable scoping rules.

Variables exiting scope are cleaned up automatically, but you can also delete references to them using the `del` keyword.

```
very_large_data = 'x' * 1_000_000_000  # a gigabyte of x!
# do things...
del very_large_data  # that gigabyte will be garbage-collected soon after
```

If you're worried about "scope pollution" for making debugging and so on easier, just refactor your code into smaller functions and/or classes (so you can stash shared state in `self.`)

Comment: I am familiar with Python's variable scoping rules and `del` but they don't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry. What is your exact question, then?

Answer (score 0):

from [What's the scope of a variable initialized in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-variable-initialized-in-an-if-statement)

> Python variables are scoped to the innermost function, class, or module in which they're assigned. Control blocks like if and while blocks don't count, so a variable assigned inside an if is still scoped to a function, class, or module.

So if you are wondering why this works:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    a = i
print(a)

>> 2
```

and why is `a` accessible outside the for loop then the answer is, this is `python` and not `c++` or `R`. Deleting them would be a non-pythonic way of doing things yet you can clearly do so forcefully by looking at the other answers