# Is a variable defined in with open as block available for the code in outer block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it legal to access the variable, `ktext`, which is defined in a `with-as` block, out of the block as the code below?

The code is as below.

```
try:
    with open("pub", "r") as f:
        ktext = f.read().strip()
except:
    ktext = ""

print(ktext)
```

Comment: Related question regarding `if`-blocks: [What's the scope of a variable initialized in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-variable-initialized-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Python, variable scope extends outside of blocks (with the exception of function and class blocks). This means you can do stuff like:

```
if True:
    a = 1

a += 1
print(a)    # 2
```

The same principle applies for `with` blocks:

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()

print(data)
```

Note that if an exception is raised, the variable isn't assigned (but in your case, you already handle this with `ktext = ""` in the except-block).

Answer (score 2):

The 'with' statement clarifies code that previously would use try...finally blocks to ensure that clean-up code is executed and the scope of variable defined within with block extends outside with block.

```
with expression [as variable]:
    with-block
```

The expression is evaluated, and it should result in an object that supports the context management protocol (that is, has **enter**() and **exit**() methods. After execution of the with-block is finished, the object's **exit**() method is called, even if the block raised an exception, and can therefore run clean-up code.

Here It would be more clean to initialize the variables before with block as variable instance might not at all get created if the with-block throws execption before variable instantiation, like

```
ktext = ""
with open("k_pub", "r") as f:
    ktext = f.read().strip()

print(ktext)
```