# Variable defined but says not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm finishing up an assignment but the thing is that it says 'restart' is undefined even though it's defined throughout the assignment.

I've had errors on where it was local so I made it global but now it says that 'restart' is undefined

```
def main():   

        global restart

        def changeMyList(myList):
            for i in range(len(myList)):
                myList[i] = myList[i].title()
            myList.sort()

        soccer_teams = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Barcelona", "Juventus", "Manchester City", "Atletico Madrid", "Borussia Dortmund"]

        team_length = len(soccer_teams)

        changeMyList(soccer_teams)

        print("|||||" + str(team_length) + " TEAMS" + "|||||")

        import random

        for team in soccer_teams:
            print(team)

        shuffle_user = input("Reshuffle? Y/N: ")
        if shuffle_user == 'y':
            random.shuffle(soccer_teams)
            print("List after first shuffle: ", soccer_teams)

            random.shuffle(soccer_teams)
            print("List after second shuffle: ", soccer_teams)
            restart = input("Run Again? Y/N: ").lower()

        if restart == 'y':
                        main()

        elif restart == 'n':
                        exit



main()
```

When I press 'n' when it asks to reshuffle it says "name 'restart' is not defined" line 32; line 40

Comment: Defined means it is set. There is a possibility of it not being set under some conditions. Please check your logic again

Comment: `global restart` doesn't create variable. It only inform function to use external/global variable when you will assign value `restart = new_value`. So at start this variable doesn't exist. When `shuffle_user` is not `y` then it doesn't run `restart = input(..)` and it doesn't create variable. So finally variable doesn't exist when you check `restart == 'y'`

Answer (score 1):

The only place in this code where `restart` is defined is:

```
restart = input("Run Again? Y/N: ").lower()
```

in the `if shuffle_user == 'y':` block. Therefore, if you answer no to the reshuffle prompt, no value is ever assigned to the `restart` variable, and the attempts to read it produce a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

`restart` is defined inside the `if` that's why you cannot reach it, the scope is inside the if:

```
restart = input("Run Again? Y/N: ").lower()
```

so you have to move it up and outside the if:

```
    restart = "n"
    if shuffle_user == 'y':
        random.shuffle(soccer_teams)
        print("List after first shuffle: ", soccer_teams)

        random.shuffle(soccer_teams)
        print("List after second shuffle: ", soccer_teams)
        input("Run Again? Y/N: ").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You rarely need to use the global keyword.  In your case, the easiest solution would be to pass restart to main() as an argument.

### Update

I took your full code and modified it so there isn't any confusion.  Also, I named restart `some_globally_accessible_var` to add clarity to what exactly is happening.  In your exact case it isn't really necessary to have `restart` defined globally.

If you are still confused about variable scope, [this](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) seems like a decent explanation of it.  Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829528/whats-the-scope-of-a-variable-initialized-in-an-if-statement) is a good StackOverflow question about variable scope within `if` statements.

```
some_globally_accessible_var = ''

def main(restart):   
        def changeMyList(myList):
            for i in range(len(myList)):
                myList[i] = myList[i].title()
            myList.sort()

        soccer_teams = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Barcelona", "Juventus", "Manchester City", "Atletico Madrid", "Borussia Dortmund"]

        team_length = len(soccer_teams)

        changeMyList(soccer_teams)

        print("|||||" + str(team_length) + " TEAMS" + "|||||")

        import random

        for team in soccer_teams:
            print(team)

        shuffle_user = input("Reshuffle? Y/N: ")
        if shuffle_user == 'y':
            random.shuffle(soccer_teams)
            print("List after first shuffle: ", soccer_teams)

            random.shuffle(soccer_teams)
            print("List after second shuffle: ", soccer_teams)
            restart = input("Run Again? Y/N: ").lower()

        if restart == 'y':
                        main(restart) #remember to pass restart to your function here!

        elif restart == 'n':
                        exit



main(some_globally_accessible_var)
```

See pppery’s answer for an explanation of your error.

Comment: Assuming you are suggesting removing the `global` keyword, this solution wouldn't work, because any attempt to modify a variable in a python function declares that variable as local, even if there is a global variable of the same name.

Comment: @pppery that’s true, but I was assuming he didn’t actually need it as a global.  I added a work around to make it globally accessible

Comment: Additionally, you need to declare `restart` using straight quotes (`restart = ''`), not curly quotes like your answer is using.

Comment: I don’t know how to do that on my phone xD

Comment: @pppery Thanks! How would I put that into the code?

Comment: The comment you responded to was me talking to the poster of this answer, pointing out a syntax error with the answer (which I then corrected). This question, to the extent it makes sense (How would you put **what** into the code), should be directed at Caleb Goodman, who wrote the answer.